# SimpleDateFormat ignores "XXX" if timezone is set to "UTC"

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I am trying to output the current datetime as UTC in the following format:
2016-01-11T14:08:42+00:00

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

final String dateString = formatter.format(new Date());
```

"dateString" should now contain "2016-01-11T14:08:42+00:00" but it contains "2016-01-11T14:08:42Z".

Without the "UTC" timezone setting I get the right format but - of course - in my specific timezone...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See the documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone):

> For formatting [using an ISO 8601 Time zone], if the offset value from GMT is 0, "Z" is produced.

So, this behaviour is expected.

You can either:

- Use the RFC 822 timezone formatter `ZZZ`; however, this produces "+0000"
- Manipulate the string to replace the final `Z`: `str.replaceAll("Z$", "+00:00")`

Comment: I think my way is simply the "wrong" way. I'll try to use 'Z' as it is/seems to be the standard. THX!

Comment: @eventhorizon I don't think your way is necessarily wrong; I find it to be unexpected behaviour to use `Z` instead of `+00:00`. I'm sure there was a good intent behind the decision, I'm just not sure what it might have been. However, sticking with `Z` might be easier.

Comment: @eventhorizon Z is a symbol for UTC+00:00 as officially defined in ISO-8601-standard. Probably the letter Z originally comes from US-military usage (Z=Zulu).