# converting date timezone format in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

Wrote below code for trying to convert date time from the value in double quotes but fails with parse exception. please advise

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z");
        Date date = format.parse("2016-02-03 10:39:29.099545 -8:00");
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this fails with parse exception.

> further more my final output should look like below format:
>   2016-01-26T12:07:41-08:00

Answer (score 3):

The representation of the time zone doesn't correspond with the string "-8:00". You can use three types of time zone representation:

1. **X** (ISO 8601 time zone):

```java
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S XXX");
Date date = format.parse("2016-02-03 10:39:29.099545 -08:00");
```

2. **Z** (RFC 822 time zone):

```java
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S Z");
Date date = format.parse("2016-02-03 10:39:29.099545 -0800");
```

3. **z** (General):

```java
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S zzz");
Date date = format.parse("2016-02-03 10:39:29.099545 GMT-08:00");
```

Check [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation

To convert from Date to the String you desire use this format:

```java
DateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
String str = format2.format(date);
```

But for ISO 8601 Time zone standard, consider this from [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) documentation:

> For formatting, if the offset value from GMT is 0, "Z" is produced

Check [SimpleDateFormat ignores “XXX” if timezone is set to “UTC”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723683/simpledateformat-ignores-xxx-if-timezone-is-set-to-utc)

Comment: my server returns 2016-02-04 08:19:11.778892-8:00

Answer (score 2):

To format a date into [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) you could use below snippet.

```
// pre Java 8
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST");
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(timeZone);
cal.set(2016, 1, 26, 12, 7, 41);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

The formatting rules of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
// Java 8
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, 1, 26, 12, 7, 41);
ZonedDateTime of = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, ZoneId.of("-0800"));
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
String format = pattern.format(of);
System.out.println(format);
```

Javadoc of [DateTimeFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

output of both snippets

```
2016-02-26T12:07:41-0800
```

Comment: where did u set the input value

Comment: @Vik What do you mean with "input value"? The date and time to format is set at `cal.set(...)` resp. `LocaldateTime.of(...)`

Comment: TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"); sorry i mean why you have hardcoded pst here?

Comment: @Vik I derive it from your example `-08:00`. See it only as a placeholder for any other timezone, in which you want to convert the date/time.